# Checking different lengths of several inputs fields in the same function

Tags: javascript

SOLVED!!
I've change the code a bite, I think now is more correct, now I have played with the event object to target the input blured.

```
    var inputHandler = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    var inputListener = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
    var msg = document.getElementById("message");

    function checkLength(e, minLength){
        el = e.target;
        if (el.value.length < minLength) {
            msg.textContent = "please, introduce at least " + minLength + " characters";
            el.style.borderColor = "red";
        }
        else{
            msg.textContent = "";
            el.style.borderColor = "green";
        }
    }

    inputHandler.onblur = function(e){checkLength(e, 3);};
    inputListener.addEventListener("blur", function(e){checkLength(e, 5);}, false);
```

Comment: make `else if (inputListener.blur) {` to `if (inputListener.blur) {`

Comment: could also do `<input pattern=".{3,}"   required title="please, introduce at least 3 characters">` ... although this would check on submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```js
function checkLength(minLegth){
    if (inputHandler.blur) {
      if (inputHandler.value.length < minLegth){
        message.textContent = "tiene que tener al menos " + minLegth + " caracteres";
        inputHandler.style.borderColor = "red";
      }
      else{
      message.textContent = "";
      inputHandler.style.borderColor = "green";
      }
    }
    if (inputListener.blur) {
      if (inputListener.value.length < minLegth){
        message.textContent = "tiene que tener al menos " + minLegth + " caracteres";
        inputListener.style.borderColor = "red";
      }
      else{
        message.textContent = "";
        inputListener.style.borderColor = "green";
      }
    }
    else{}
    }
```